# Servlet threw load() exception

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I know this error has been posted before but I can't understand the stack trace and would love somebodies help.

Basically when I enter the application the `getValue("client")` is null:

```
HttpSession validuser = request.getSession(); 

if (validuser.getValue("client") == null) {  
    response.sendRedirect("/profile/factfind/includes/session_timeout.jsp");
}
```

And I'm thinking it's something to do with the following error:

```
2013-01-09 13:14:35 NamingContextListener[/Tomcat-Standalone/localhost/profile]: Creating JNDI naming context
2013-01-09 13:14:35 StandardManager[/profile]: Seeding random number generator class java.security.SecureRandom
2013-01-09 13:14:35 StandardManager[/profile]: Seeding of random number generator has been completed
2013-01-09 13:14:35 StandardContext[/profile]: Posting standard context attributes
2013-01-09 13:14:35 StandardContext[/profile]: Configuring application event listeners
2013-01-09 13:14:35 StandardContext[/profile]: Sending application start events
2013-01-09 13:14:35 StandardContext[/profile]: Starting filters
2013-01-09 13:14:35 StandardContext[/profile]: Starting completed
2013-01-09 13:14:37 StandardContext[/profile]: Servlet /profile threw load() exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

An error occurred at line: -1 in the jsp file: null

Generated servlet error:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file



    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:248)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:343)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:427)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:142)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:240)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:187)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:888)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:768)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3484)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3710)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:538)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostDeployer.addChild(StandardHostDeployer.java:667)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:216)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:217)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:253)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1222)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostDeployer.install(StandardHostDeployer.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.install(StandardHost.java:762)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:377)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:808)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1156)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:450)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:2213)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.execute(Catalina.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.process(Catalina.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:151)
```

The session exists in a different application that then loads "profile" so I'm not too sure what happens when one launches the other.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is your code snippet from a JSP or a servlet?  I am guessing JSP.  Note that the stack trace indicates the JSP could not be compliled.  One thought HttpSession.getValue() is a deprecated method.  Try replacing this with "getAttribute()" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the fix for me was the same as some forums had suggested. I create a new Tomcat installation in a directory with no spaces (i.e `C:\Tomcat4.1`) and that worked.

Don't know why or how but it did.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a problem

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

An error occurred at line: -1 in the jsp file: null
```

Cleanup your project (or manually remove all .class files) then try to compile from scratch. If error gone - check it should work. If not - you should apparently get this first error gone.

Comment: I don't have the source code... so I wouldn't want to remove all .class files. It's an web app that I have to deploy from a copy and paste of a Tomcat directory :)

Can you think of any way to find that "null" jsp file?

Comment: how are you saying you do not have source code. what is compiled then?

Comment: I have the .class files but not the .java files.

Answer (score -1):

It seems `getValue(String)` method is deprecated. so try the following code `null == validuser.getAttribute(String)`

Comment: Tried it... no difference. Both values are null.

Comment: I meant the same when said it should work as non-deprecated method.